# Outputting to Console and Log in one command? Java

Tags: java, logging, console, stdout

I am trying to find an elegant way to remove extra lines of code from my Java application

I have seperate lines of code that output to console and log file like below:

```
catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("The Database connection failed to open check username/password and connection url are valid.");
                logger.info("The Database connection failed to open check username/password and connection url are valid.");
                end(2);
            }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use stdout to fire it at both the console and log file.

I considered making a function that would would do this but It would be too complex deciding the level, whether to output to console or not.

Is there any quick and smart way to achieve what I am trying to do.

I guess you could say , what does a few extra lines of code do harm as my program functions perfectly, just trying to over engineer it.

Comment: Why not just configure your logger, so that it outputs to the console **and** file?

Comment: I am using java.util.logging which is precompiled

Comment: ``java.util.logging`` afaik also provides the possibility to configure multiple appenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`System.setOut()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and provide a subclass of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), doing whatever you wan't...

If that seems unnecessary work, just put it in a method...

```
// Warning, untested code!

enum Level {DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR}

public static Logger logger; // Whereever you get this one...

public static void log(Level level, String s) {
    System.out.println(level.name() + ": " + s);
    switch (level) {
         case INFO:
             logger.info(s);
             break;

         // The other levels...
    }
}
```

Personally, I made my own logger (really simple):

```
L.i("Testing logging");
```

outputs

```
[INFO , 12:07:41.455, utill.log.Test.main.10]: Testing logging
```

It is configurable, and if you need to redirect it to a file, or another stream, it's really easy. But I guess logging frameworks like [self4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) will do as well.

Comment: Ok I guess this means I will need several functions, one for each level in log

Comment: serupticious: Well, you can also give the level (enum or String) as a parameter...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like that?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class LoggerTest {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class.getSimpleName());

    public LoggerTest() {
        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("test.log");
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            logger.addHandler(fh);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Hoppla");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Here you'll find some more info: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to have helped.